# sed delete all occurences of pattern in each line

Tags: bash, sed

The following command doesn't repeat the process for each occurence in one line...

input_file.txt :

```
<!--:nl-->hond <span>bob</span><!--:fr-->chien <span>bob</span><!--:nl-->kat<!--:fr-->chat
<!--:nl-->hond<!--:fr-->chien<!--:nl-->kat<!--:fr-->chat
```

wrong sed command :

```
sed -e 's/\(\<\!--\:nl\--\>\).*\(\<\!--\:fr\--\>\)/\1\2/g' input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

current output_file.txt result :

```
<!--:nl--><!--:fr-->chat
```

**desired output_file.txt result :**

```
chien <span>bob</span>chat
chienchat
```

**[EDIT] hond, chien, kat and chat may have HTML tags around them that need to be kept...**

Comment: Ah, so this has turned from something that could justifiably be solved using a simple text processing tool, into something that has to preserve arbitrary HTML. Don't use sed for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/<!--:nl-->[^<]*<!--:fr-->//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you in same.

```
awk -F'<!--:nl-->|<!--:fr-->' '{print $3$5}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making strings `<!--:nl-->` OR `<!--:fr-->` as field separators and then printing 3rd and 5th columns of the line(as per your output required).